# Pypsark unpack column of nested lists of strings with varying length

Tags: python, list, pyspark, nested

I have a pyspark dataframe like the one below containing nested lists of varying unknown lengths:

```
ID          Features
Sample1     ["AATC", 0.01, 1]
Sample2     [["AATC", 0.01, 1], ["AATG", 0.02, 0], ["AAAA", 0.5, 0]]
Sample3     ["TGCC", 0.04, 0]
```

I need to unpack the dataframe so that it retains the ID for each nested list and the following columns:

```
ID          BioID    Pvalue    Significance
Sample1     "AATC"    0.01          1
Sample2     "AATC"    0.01          1
Sample2     "AATG"    0.02          0
Sample2     "AAAA"    0.50          0
Sample3     "TGCC"    0.04          0
```

I tried explode, but it gives me back more lists:

```
df.select("ID", F.explode("results")).show(5)

ID          col    
Sample1     ["AATC", "AATC", "AATG", "AAAA", "TGCC"]
Sample2     [0.01, 0.02, 0.50, 0.04]
Sample2     [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]             
Sample2     ["AATC", "AATC", "AATG", "AAAA", "TGCC"]             
Sample3     [0.01, 0.02, 0.50, 0.04]
```

Edit: adding schema based on suggestions

```
root
 |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- features: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @anky. Posted.

Comment: is the schema that u posted from the exploded dataframe or from the initial one? the schema for ur nested list in initial dataframe should be  `|-- Features: array (nullable = true)|-- element: array (containsNull = true)-- element: string (containsNull = true)`

Comment: It's indeed the schema I posted above. Looks like it's an array of strings that looks like a list. But your answer works great for the schema you described so thanks for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have **`nested list`** with the schema as shown below *( **Array->Array->string** )*, you can use higher order function **`transform`**( *to assemble desired columns into structs in the array*) with **`inline`**( *to explode array of structs*) to get your desired output.

```
df.show(truncate=False)

#+-------+--------------------------------------------------+
#|ID     |Features                                          |
#+-------+--------------------------------------------------+
#|Sample1|[[AATC, 0.01, 1]]                                 |
#|Sample2|[[AATC, 0.01, 1], [AATG, 0.02, 0], [AAAA, 0.5, 0]]|
#|Sample3|[[TGCC, 0.04, 0]]                                 |
#+-------+--------------------------------------------------+

df.printSchema()

#root
# |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
# |-- Features: array (nullable = true)
# |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
# |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("Features", F.expr("""transform(Features,x-> struct(x[0] as BioID, x[1] as Pvalue, x[2] as Significance))"""))\
  .select("ID", F.expr("""inline(Features)""")).show()

#+-------+-----+------+------------+
#|     ID|BioID|Pvalue|Significance|
#+-------+-----+------+------------+
#|Sample1| AATC|  0.01|           1|
#|Sample2| AATC|  0.01|           1|
#|Sample2| AATG|  0.02|           0|
#|Sample2| AAAA|   0.5|           0|
#|Sample3| TGCC|  0.04|           0|
#+-------+-----+------+------------+
```